# DJANGO4: names_to_path raise FieldError "Cannot resolve keyword '%s' into field. " Why does django cant resolve the keyword 'fatura'?

Tags: django, django-queryset

DJANGO: names_to_path raise FieldError "Cannot resolve keyword '%s' into field. "

I want to return a queryset with all related records.
Something like this:

```
r = Repasse.objects.filter(fatura__id = 9)
```

But I get an error... django seems not to be able to resolve 'fatura':
names_to_path raise FieldError "Cannot resolve keyword '%s' into field. "

So I've tryed this raw query:

```
r = Repasse.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM imob_repasse INNER JOIN imob_fatura ON imob_repasse.id_fatura_id  = imob_fatura.id ')
```

It returns exacly what I am looking for, returns all Repasse joined with Fatura.

Can't see what is wrong.

Models are set as this:

```
class Fatura(models.Model):
    datavencimento = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    valorfaturado = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

class Repasse(models.Model):
    id_contrato = models.ForeignKey(Contrato, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)  ##RELATIONSHIP##
    id_fatura = models.OneToOneField(Fatura, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)  ##RELATIONSHIP##
    valorrepasse = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
```

Can't see what is wrong.
I beleave raw SQL woud be brute force...Could it be any setup wrong?
Why does django cant resolve the keyword 'fatura' ?

Answer (score 0):

your relational key field name is id_fatura that's why you are getting field name error, so use query like

```
r = Repasse.objects.filter(id_fatura_id=9)
```